# VLC-can't playback online video

Tags: ios, vlc

i'm trying to use VLC to playback youtube online video for `IOS5`. 
I set a `NSURL` to `MVLCMovieViewController`, use code like this:

```
NSString *conntentURL = @"http://www.youtube.com/watch?v=FWKYriGgmCo";//(it's a workable link)
NSURL *url = [NSURL URLWithString:connectURL];
MVLCMovieViewController *movieViewController = [[MVLCMovieViewController alloc] init];
movieViewController.url = url;
[self presentModalViewController:movieViewController animated:YES];
[movieViewController release];
```

run the app, but i got a stop at http.c file with a hint "Program received signal "EXC_BAD_ACCESS"" near code:

```
 p_sys->psz_user_agent = var_InheritString(p_access, "http-user-agent");
    for(char *p = p_sys->psz_user_agent; *p, p++)
```

So does `VLC` support online playbacking? Or what should to be modified so that i can play a url directly on ios?

Thanks a lot for your help in advance!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I've done a lot of work on the VLC iOS source code, to try to get it to handle RTP and UDP streams. The short answer is that I didn't get it to work for those protocols but HTTP works, and the blocking seems to be at the OS level.

If you want the details on what I did to make VLC compile correctly and work on the latest XCode, please read the following forum thread https://forum.videolan.org/viewtopic.php?f=12&t=108691

Since YouTube seems to be HTTP, it should work but your mileage may vary.
Hope this helps.

Comment: Thanks a lot!  I've already let it work properly now, just make sure if you play online video like youtube, you should parse the url correctly.